# Divide a linked list into half and return the second half

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

This was a programming question that I did wrong.There was a partial code give as follows:

```
public class SingleLinkedList<E> {
   private Node<E> head;
   private int size = 0;

   private static class Node<E> {
     private E data;
     private Node<E> next;

     /** Creates a new node with a null next field
         @param dataItem  The data stored
     */
     private Node(E data) {
       data = dataItem;
       next = null;
     }

    /** Creates a new node that references another node
         @param dataItem  The data stored
         @param nodeRef  The node referenced by new node
     */
     private Node(E dataItem, Node<E> nodeRef) {
       data = dataItem;
       next = nodeRef;
     }
  }

}
```

My task was to create a method that divides the linked list in half leaving the first half of the elements in the original list and returning a new SingleLinkedList containing the second half of the list.If the number of elements is odd, then the extra element should go with the first half.I could not do it.Then my teacher gave answer like the following:

```
SingleLinkedList<E> newlist = new SingleLinkedList<E>();
 newlist.head =  temp.next; 
temp.next= null; 
return newlist
```

However, I'm not even getting the answer.I am a beginner.I would appreciate if someone can explain this problem.

Comment: That's only part of the answer, the part that splits the list into two lists.  You still have to write code to find the place at which to split the list (identified as `temp` in the solution code).  Given a list of length `n`, how would you calculate the index of the split point?  That's actually not a programming question, it's basic arithmetic.

Comment: Write a method to write through the list until it's end. Then think how to modify it to make iterator `temp` stop in the center

Comment: The answer was given by my teacher.I am not understanding what he is saying.

Comment: This is not full answer, this is method to divide the list into two lists.

Comment: Your teacher only gave you a third of the answer. --- *Part 1:* You need to find the halfway point, by taking half of the list `size`, then iterating until you find that middle node, i.e. what is to become the last node of the first half (`temp`). *Part 2:* Assign the second half of the chain to a new list (first 2 lines), and terminate the chain of the first half (line 3). *Part 3:* Set the size of both lists. --- Your teacher only gave you part 2, and is actually misguiding you by showing that `return` statement, because the work is not done yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which you have provided by your teacher is incomplete. Anyways I can give you two ways to find the pointer to second half:

1. If you want a pointer to refer second half in the same list.

   ```
   private static Node getSecondHalfInSameList(Node head) {
       Node fastRunner = head, slowRunner = head;
       while(fastRunner != null && fastRunner.next != null) {
           slowRunner = slowRunner.next;
           fastRunner = fastRunner.next.next;
       }
       return slowRunner;
   }
   ```
2. If you want to create a new list with all the nodes in the second half, then you can do the following.Here first we find the middle node then we will create a new list from second half by creating new node iterating from middle node to the end of the list.

   ```
   private static Node getSecondHalfByCreatingNewNodes(Node head) {
       Node mid = getMiddleNode(head);
       Node newHead = new Node(mid.data);
       mid = mid.next;
       Node tail = newHead, temp;
       while(mid != null) {
           temp = new Node(mid.data);
           tail.next = temp;
           tail = temp;
       }
       return newHead;
   }

   private static Node getMiddleNode(Node head) {
       Node fastRunner = head, slowRunner = head;
       while(fastRunner != null && fastRunner.next != null) {
           slowRunner = slowRunner.next;
           fastRunner = fastRunner.next.next;
       }
       return slowRunner;
   }
   ```